# emailext EmailDL usage outside of email stage

Tags: jenkins

How do I use the email-id in prior stages from the variable `EmailDL` which I have used in the email text plugin in the declarative pipeline template in the last stage?
Is there any Global variable for the `EmailDL`/`recipient`/`To` like `$BUILDID` which can be used?

we have `EmailDL` to receive Job Status `Emails` to collect the email id & use it in the template

```
post {
  always {
    emailext (
                body:
                subject: "XXXXXX", 
                mimeType: 'text/html', 
                to: "${EmailDL}"
    )
  }
}
```

All works good but how do I reuse the parameter `EmailDL` outside of the Post stages?

Comment: Tried using echo "$EmailDL" , echo "$emailext.EmailDL" but does not get expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest define it in environment like this

```
 environment {
   EmailDL = "abc@.com"
 }
```

and use it anywhere using `${EmailDL}`